# Select database rows within a column

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

I have set up a Jupyter Notebook that calls my description column within a table from a PostgreSQL database and apply a Machine learning model from the Ibm watson studio API to this data.

I was able to correctly get a response back with a prediction, but the problem is that my datas are all being displayed and read as a single object instead of an individual object for each row.

My goal is to apply the model to each of these description rows but as you can see below the prediction is applied to the column itself, not to the rows:

```
{
  "collection": [
    {
      "top_class": "hot",
      "text": "{\"description\":{\"0\":\"Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvjuoigv gvj ifcil ,ghn fgbcggtc   yfctgg h vgchbvju.\",\"1\":\"Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjhn oikgjvn uhnhgv 09iuvhb  oiuvh boiuhb mkjhv mkiuhygv m,khbgv mkjhgv mkjhgv.\",\"2\":\"Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b hb bnjb bhb bhn bn vf vbgfc vbgv nbhgv bb nb nbh nj mjhbv mkjhbv nmjhgbv nmkn\",\"3\":\"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx\",\"4\":\"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx\",\"5\":\"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx\",\"6\":\"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx\",\"7\":\"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx\",\"8\":\"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx\",\"9\":\"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx\",\"10\":\"lorem sivbnogc hbiuygv bnjiuygv bmkjygv nmjhgv.\"}}",
      "classes": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.40859634691282776,
          "class_name": "hot"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 0.2325080584859929,
          "class_name": "cold"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "classifier_id": "7818d2s519-nlc-1311",
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/7818d2s519-nlc-1311"
}
```

And for clarity, the expected output should look like this:

```
{
  "classifier_id": "7818d2s519-nlc-1311",
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/7818d2s519-nlc-1311",
  "collection": [
    {
      "text": "Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b hb bnjb bhb bhn bn vf vbgfc vbgv nbhgv bb nb nbh nj mjhbv mkjhbv nmjhgbv nmkn.",
      "top_class": "cold",
      "classes": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.89084859929,
          "class_name": "cold"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 0.23250805848,
          "class_name": "hot"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjhn oikgjvn uhnhgv 09iuvhb  oiuvh boiuhb mkjhv mkiuhygv m,khbgv mkjhgv mkjhgv.",
      "top_class": "hot",
      "classes": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.1084859929,
          "class_name": "cold"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 0.99250805848,
          "class_name": "hot"
        }
      ]
   },
   {
     "text": "Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx.",
     "top_class": "cold",
     "classes": [
       {
         "confidence": 0.7084859929,
         "class_name": "cold"
       },
       {
         "confidence": 0.19250805848,
         "class_name": "hot"
       }
     ]
  }

etc.....
```

This is my python code in the Notebook:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageClassifierV1
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import json

# connect to the database
conn_string = 'host={} port={}  dbname={}  user={}  password={}'.format('119.203.10.242', 5432, 'mydb', 'locq', 'Mypass***')
conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

# select the description column
data_df_1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT description from public."search_product"', con=conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e)

# connect to the Watson Studio API
natural_language_classifier = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
    iam_apikey='F76ugy8hv1s3sr87buhb7564vb7************'
)

# apply the model to the datas
classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', [{'text':data_df_1.to_json()}]).get_result()

# print the result in json
print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))
```

And, an example of what the data structure look like:

```
Id  description
0   Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvju...
1   Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjh...
2   Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b h...
3   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
4   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
5   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
6   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
7   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
8   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
9   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
10  Lorem sivbnogc hbiuygv bnjiuygv bmkjygv nmjhgv...
```

Is there any ways I can achieve that with some python code?
Or is there a way to call the rows within the column instead of the column itself?

### Edit

Having applied @Peter solution, the data is correctly formatted but I get this error now:

Full output for clarity:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-9d8e7cf98a41> in <module>()
      1 import json
      2 
----> 3 classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', reshaped).get_result()
      4 
      5 print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/natural_language_classifier_v1.py in classify_collection(self, classifier_id, collection, **kwargs)
    152         if collection is None:
    153             raise ValueError('collection must be provided')
--> 154         collection = [self._convert_model(x, ClassifyInput) for x in collection]
    155 
    156         headers = {}

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/natural_language_classifier_v1.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    152         if collection is None:
    153             raise ValueError('collection must be provided')
--> 154         collection = [self._convert_model(x, ClassifyInput) for x in collection]
    155 
    156         headers = {}

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_service.py in _convert_model(val, classname)
    461         if classname is not None and not hasattr(val, "_from_dict"):
    462             if isinstance(val, str):
--> 463                 val = json_import.loads(val)
    464             val = classname._from_dict(dict(val))
    465         if hasattr(val, "_to_dict"):

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353         """
    354         try:
--> 355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
    357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Watson documentation for the `classify_collection` method ([link](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-classifier#classify-multiple-phrases)), you need to package your phrases into a JSON object with a single top-level key `"collection"` whose value is a list of objects, each with key=`"text"` and value=phrase.

Try something like this:

```
# package phrases into format required by Watson
reshaped = json.dumps({'collection': [{'text' : t} for t in data_df_1['description']]})

# apply the model to the datas
classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', reshaped).get_result()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will try this out now.

Comment: I get this error when I print the classes now: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Running `print(json.dumps(reshaped, indent=2))` give me the correct format so thanks a lot for that! But If I add the `classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', reshaped).get_result()` and run `print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))` this is where I'm getting the `JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: Try printing `classes` instead of json-dumping it?

Comment: The full error output is pointing towards this line like this: 
 `----> 3 classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', reshaped).get_result()`

Comment: Just updated the question to include an Edit with the full error output.

Comment: @locq, sorry - I hadn't read the API docs well enough. Looks like it's expecting a JSON string. Try my edited solution, which converts the `reshaped` dict to JSON.

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate your help. I get this new error now: JSONDecodeError: `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: Just updated the questions to include this new error full traceback.

Comment: Do you know what's causing this issue?

Comment: I have no more specific suggestions, sorry :/